# postgres where or where based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns {price, discounted price, discount start date, discount end date}, i need to use where statement to filter prices from < to based on price column BUT if today is between the 2 discount dates i should filter based on the discounted price, so WT HELL, how to do that in sql raw or typeorm , using posting btw[image]

Comment: Please show both sample input and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE

Comment: Please post table descriptions (ddl) along with sample input and desired results of that data. Post all as formatted text (see [Senseful](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)) or better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). **Do Not** post images - [see why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use () to group multiple where statement as one side of OR operator.

Comment: Please follow advice in the comments to clarify the question and how you solved it. You can just edit your initial query into the question, show what it returned and how it was wrong, then edit your improved/fixed query into the answer.